# div order if they have certain class, javascript

Tags: javascript

I wonder if this possible, let's say I have controller which returns me some parameters, let's called module, so I basically generate html content based on this, and this refresh each certain amount of time via ajax.

So, one of the properties is an alert, if alert is true, I add a class to the element, let's called it warning, so at the end, it generates something like this:

```
 <div class="mod1"></div>
 <div class="mod2"></div>
 <div class="mod3"></div>
 <div class="mod4"></div>
 <div class="mod5 warning"></div>
```

If there any chance to place the divs with the warning class on top only using javascript???

Any adviced would be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Yes, you can use the DOM API to reorder the elements.

Comment: Wrap that in a parent div -- I'll call it `home`.  Look through your warnings *backwards* and when you add the `warning` class, just insert that element into the `home` div.   It will re-order properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery, this is a one approach:

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmbLH)

HTML:

```
<div id="messages">
<div class='message'> message 1</div>
<div class='message'> message 2</div>
<div class='message'> message 3</div>
<div class='message warning'> message 4</div>
<div class='message warning'> message 5</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  var clones = $('div.warning');
  $('div.warning').remove();
  $('#messages').prepend(clones);
})
```